# JQuery Select2 With MVC5, Ajax : Not calling controller method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-select2

I have been pondering on how to make Select2 work for a whole day. After reading a lot of posts, answers and guides also following docs I can't make Select2 work. It is not even calling a method I want it to call.

**//Edit I can't type in the select that is created on website.**

My desire is to create multiple select like this [link]https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox

My html:

```
<select class="form-control IngridientsSelect" name="IngridientsSelect" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

My script:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".IngridientsSelect").select2({
        placeholder: "Select an Item",
        allowClear: true,
        style: "display: inline-block",
        minimumInputLength: 1, //you can specify a min. query length to return results
        ajax: {
            url: '@Url.Action("GetIngridients", "Dishes")',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, search) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            id: item.id,
                            text: item.name,
                        }
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        templateResult: function (item) {
            if (item.loading) return item.text;
            return item.text;
        }
    })
```

});

My Method:

```
public JsonResult GetIngridients(string q)
    {
        var items = db.getIngridients();
        var filteredItems = items.Select(n => new {id = n.Id, name = n.Name }).ToList();
        return Json(filteredItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Unfortunatelly nothing.

Comment: Code seems fine to me, can you provide a live link for it?

Comment: What is a live link?

Comment: Live link means a public URL though which you can show your implementation. Does it make sense?

Comment: https://github.com/barteq100/KitchenBook here you go

Comment: You seem to be confused about how a web application works.  Client-side code (Select2) cannot "call a method" in your server-side code (ASP).  All it can do is issue an AJAX request and then use the response data.  So, check that your request URL is being correctly constructed and that your server can handle that request properly.  Try viewing the page source to see what URL is generated by `@Url.Action("GetIngridients", "Dishes")`, and then check that the URL is working properly in your browser, without Select2.

Comment: Also, FYI, the correct spelling is "Ingredients".

Comment: I know but I misspelled early so the "Ingridients" stayed. Also I resolved  the issue already. For some reason I don't know why yet my Bundled Jquery didn't handle the jquery properly so I had to add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`